# Performing click of a link button from a webservice in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice and a default.aspx page in c#.
I want to perform a click of the link button on default page from the webservice.
How can i call the linkbutton of the default.aspx from the webservice?
Please suggest a genuine way for doing this.

Comment: you can't. explain what you are trying to accomplish, and we can explain how it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services cannot "click" buttons. They can return data or perform certain process on their end; you in turn can hook into any callback function after the web service finishes processing to perform the click on your end.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "URLTOWEBService.here",
  success: function(){
    //webservice returned successfully
    performClick();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What does the button do? Instead of trying to click it remotely you should change architecture of your system to invoke logic under button via web service.

Comment: we want to do it remotely and that to by calling that link button in the webservice.we are steady with the architecture and dont want to change that.Is their a way to call the link button?

Answer (score 0):

the closest you can get is if you return a javascript that "clicks" the button and is evaluated by the browser client.

The webservice itself can't do jack since its running on the server.